# How to parse EXIF GPS information to lat,lng decimal numbers

Tags: gps

```
"EXIF_GPSAltitude": "(220.279)",
"EXIF_GPSLatitude": "(55) (40.711) (0)",
"EXIF_GPSLatitudeRef": "N",
"EXIF_GPSLongitude": "(8) (30.2282) (0)",
```

How should i understand the above example as degree, min, sec?

Some EXIF data that I extracted has metadata listed as above. Are these formats specified anywhere? Or should I expect a lot of different formats of gps positions in EXIF?

I need to write a method that gives the lat,lng as decimal numbers based on EXIF data, and I am unsure about how many different formats I should expect to be able to parse (I will learn this over time) and this question is mostly about the above examples. I know the degree is 55 and 8, but not sure if its 30 mins and 0.22*60 secs, and in that case, why is the 0 there?

Comment: What OS? You might be interested in exiftool http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool . There is an executable for Win or Mac that I've used successfully (Windows batchfiles in my case) to extract coordinate info from photos.

Comment: What platform are you using to parse the information?  What are you looking to convert it to?

Comment: I am converting to lat,lng decimal/double values and it was in C#. I simply needed the information that the answer gave.

Comment: In case anyone's wondering why we'd want to do this - so that you can paste the coordinates into google and quickly find out where a point is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [this page](http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/TagNames/GPS.html), the latitude and longitude values could be in (1) degrees, (2) degrees and decimal minutes, or (3) degrees, minutes, and decimal seconds.

In your example, (2) is a decimal value and (3) is zero, so you have degrees, decimal minutes.

So, you'll have to some checks on the three values to determine which format is being used.

Comment: According to the exif standard, there are three "rational" fields for each, containing degrees, minutes, and seconds.  exiftool normalizes imporoper decimal degrees into D,M,S while assigning these values, (exiftool -GPSLongitude="0.5 90 63.12345" junk.jpg" -> GPS Longitude: 2 deg 1' 3.12" W")   So if you need decimal degrees, you do dd=x0+x1/60.+x2/3600. and could ignore the non-normalization.

Answer (score 14):

EXIF stores GPS coords as `rational64u` which is a list of six unsigned whole numbers in the following order:

```
[
   degreesNumerator, degreesDenominator, 
   minutesNumerator, minutesDenominator, 
   secondsNumerator, secondsDenominator
]
```

The format is consistent, and it looks like the tool you are using has already divided each pair into decimal numbers, so what you have is:

```
Lat: 55°   40.711' 0"
Lng:  8°  30.2282' 0"
```

If you want to convert to a single decimal number:

```
= Degrees + Minutes/60 + Seconds/3600
```

Comment: If you have the raw exif values the denominator has to be taken into account, it's usually 1 for Degrees and Minutes but seems to vary for Seconds:
(Degrees = degreesNumerator / degreesDenominator), 
(Minutes = minutesNumerator / minutesDenominator), 
(Seconds = secondsNumerator / secondsDenominator), 


After which the calculation above works just fine.. this one threw me for a loop.

Answer (score 12):

Exiftool will output the coordinates in low precision decimal if you use the -n switch.  You can get more precision with -c switch and give the desired quantity of digits behind the decimal:

```
exiftool -c '%.6f' -GPSPosition filename.jpg
```

Shows position with 6 digits behind the decimal, which is good for finding a place within 5 inches.

Comment: Note to self: you can still use this even if you're just dumping every property as text with `-json` and doing the parsing for individual fields with `jq`.

Comment: > Shows position with 6 digits behind the decimal

There is also a blank space and single directional character (N,S,E,W) appended to the floating point number. eg: `31.304792 N`.

Comment: Plain old `exiftool -n filename.jpg` worked great for me. Per https://exiftool.org/forum/index.php?topic=3687.0: "You can either use the -n option, which will returns numerical values for all tags, or add a # to an individual tag name (ie. -filesize#) to do this for a single tag." Thanks Billious!

Answer (score 1):

Improving on Kirt's improvements:

```
function getExifGpsInfo ($fullname) 
{
 'Fullname: ' + $fullname
 $imageProperties =New-Object -TypeName System.Drawing.Bitmap -ArgumentList $fullname
 if($imageProperties.PropertyItems|?{($_.id -eq 2) -or ($_.id -eq 4)}){
  [double]$LatDegrees = (([System.BitConverter]::ToInt32( $imageProperties.GetPropertyItem(2).Value, 0)) / ([System.BitConverter]::ToInt32( $imageProperties.GetPropertyItem(2).Value, 4)));
  [double]$LatMinutes = ([System.BitConverter]::ToInt32( $imageProperties.GetPropertyItem(2).Value, 8)) / ([System.BitConverter]::ToInt32( $imageProperties.GetPropertyItem(2).Value, 12));
  [double]$LatSeconds = ([System.BitConverter]::ToInt32( $imageProperties.GetPropertyItem(2).Value, 16)) / ([System.BitConverter]::ToInt32( $imageProperties.GetPropertyItem(2).Value, 20));
  [char]$LatRef       = [System.BitConverter]::ToChar( $imageProperties.GetPropertyItem(1).Value, 0)
  [double]$LonDegrees = (([System.BitConverter]::ToInt32( $imageProperties.GetPropertyItem(4).Value, 0)) / ([System.BitConverter]::ToInt32( $imageProperties.GetPropertyItem(4).Value, 4)));
  [double]$LonMinutes = ([System.BitConverter]::ToInt32( $imageProperties.GetPropertyItem(4).Value, 8)) / ([System.BitConverter]::ToInt32( $imageProperties.GetPropertyItem(4).Value, 12));
  [double]$LonSeconds = ([System.BitConverter]::ToInt32( $imageProperties.GetPropertyItem(4).Value, 16)) / ([System.BitConverter]::ToInt32( $imageProperties.GetPropertyItem(4).Value, 20));
  [char]$LonRef       = [System.BitConverter]::ToChar( $imageProperties.GetPropertyItem(3).Value, 0)

  "$LatDegrees°$LatMinutes'$LatSeconds.0""$LatRef $LonDegrees°$LonMinutes'$LonSeconds.0""$LonRef"

  If($LatRef -eq "S") { $LatSign = "-" } else { $LatSign = "" }
  If($LonRef -eq "W") { $LonSign = "-" } else { $LonSign = "" }

  $LatSign + [string]([math]::Round(($LatDegrees + $LatMinutes/60 + $LatSeconds/3600), 7)) + ", " + $LonSign + [string]([math]::Round(($LonDegrees + $LonMinutes/60 + $LonSeconds/3600), 7))

  "Latitude:  $LatSign$LatDegrees; $LatMinutes; $LatSeconds"
  "Longitude: $LonSign$LonDegrees; $LonMinutes; $LonSeconds"
  }  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I used this batch file to get file names, date/time and decimal degree

positions.

**************start lalo.bat
'-n forces signed decimal degrees
exift -n d:\util\00ymp*.jpg >fud
'strfile one string per line (spaces ok)
findstr /G:"strfile" fud >>fum
**********end lalo.bat

produces output

File Name                       : 0104171345.jpg
GPS Date/Time                   : 2017:01:04 21:45:19Z
GPS Position                    : 46.9997367777778 -117.3392105
File Name                       : 0104171355.jpg
GPS Date/Time                   : 2017:01:04 21:55:52Z
GPS Position                    : 46.99622725 -117.307495111111
File Name                       : 0104171402.jpg
GPS Date/Time                   : 2017:01:04 22:02:02Z
GPS Position                    : 47.0075378333333 -117.284553527778
File Name                       : 0104171404.jpg
GPS Date/Time                   : 2017:01:04 22:04:51Z
GPS Position                    : 47.0222473055556 -117.275527944444
File Name                       : 0104171405.jpg
GPS Date/Time                   : 2017:01:04 22:05:40Z
GPS Position                    : 47.0269584444444 -117.269523611111

File Name                       : 0112171921.jpg
File Name                       : 0112171921a.jpg
File Name                       : 0112171921b.jpg
File Name                       : 0120171623.jpg
File Name                       : 0120171623a.jpg
File Name                       : 0120171624.jpg

File Name                       : 0120171626.jpg
GPS Date/Time                   : 2017:01:21 00:26:49Z
GPS Position                    : 48.7900199722222 -117.290061944444
File Name                       : 0120171628.jpg
GPS Date/Time                   : 2017:01:21 00:28:44Z
GPS Position                    : 48.7907943611111 -117.292045583333

File Name                       : 0122170942.jpg
File Name                       : 0122170942a.jpg
File Name                       : 0122170948.jpg
File Name                       : 0122170948a.jpg

File Name                       : 0122170950.jpg
GPS Date/Time                   : 2017:01:22 17:50:12Z
GPS Position                    : 48.7828292777778 -117.287322972222
File Name                       : 0122170950a.jpg
GPS Date/Time                   : 2017:01:22 17:50:16Z
GPS Position                    : 48.7828483333333 -117.287322972222
File Name                       : 0122170950b.jpg
GPS Date/Time                   : 2017:01:22 17:50:38Z
GPS Position                    : 48.7828178333333 -117.28733825

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Jason for the formula to convert to decimal, and to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45136895/extracting-gps-numerical-values-from-byte-array-using-powershell

```
function getGPS ($fullname) 
{
 'Fullname: ' + $fullname
 $imageProperties =New-Object -TypeName System.Drawing.Bitmap -ArgumentList $fullname
 if($imageProperties.PropertyItems|?{($_.id -eq 2) -or ($_.id -eq 4)}){
  [double]$LatDegrees = (([System.BitConverter]::ToInt32( $imageProperties.GetPropertyItem(2).Value, 0)) / ([System.BitConverter]::ToInt32( $imageProperties.GetPropertyItem(2).Value, 4)));
  [double]$LatMinutes = ([System.BitConverter]::ToInt32( $imageProperties.GetPropertyItem(2).Value, 8)) / ([System.BitConverter]::ToInt32( $imageProperties.GetPropertyItem(2).Value, 12));
  [double]$LatSeconds = ([System.BitConverter]::ToInt32( $imageProperties.GetPropertyItem(2).Value, 16)) / ([System.BitConverter]::ToInt32( $imageProperties.GetPropertyItem(2).Value, 20));
  [double]$LonDegrees = (([System.BitConverter]::ToInt32( $imageProperties.GetPropertyItem(4).Value, 0)) / ([System.BitConverter]::ToInt32( $imageProperties.GetPropertyItem(4).Value, 4)));
  [double]$LonMinutes = ([System.BitConverter]::ToInt32( $imageProperties.GetPropertyItem(4).Value, 8)) / ([System.BitConverter]::ToInt32( $imageProperties.GetPropertyItem(4).Value, 12));
  [double]$LonSeconds = ([System.BitConverter]::ToInt32( $imageProperties.GetPropertyItem(4).Value, 16)) / ([System.BitConverter]::ToInt32( $imageProperties.GetPropertyItem(4).Value, 20));
  "Latitude: $LatDegrees;$LatMinutes;$LatSeconds"
  "Longitude: $LonDegrees;$LonMinutes;$LonSeconds"
  "DECLatitude: " + ([int]$LatDegrees +($LatMinutes/60) +($LatSeconds/60))
  "DECLongitude: " + ([int]$LonDegrees +($LonMinutes/60) +($LonSeconds/60))
}}
```

getGPS D:\pics\mypic.jpg

Fullname: P:\IMG_0014.JPG
Latitude: 42;32.27;0
Longitude: 82;52.58;0
DECLatitude: 42.5378333333333
DECLongitude: 82.8763333333333

Comment: Oh come on, will some bored programmer please make a Javascript page to do this?  Paste in the input data, choose options, push a button. Not rocket science.